# Conditional Formatting with formula wont apply styles across multiple rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I read loads of answers here, but none of them applies to my issue I think.

I need to have a coloured column based on a dropdown list value. 
If it's Not Paid, the A column has to be red if it's Paid, it has to be green.

When I apply `=K12="Not Paid"` formula, styles apply only for only one cell. if I shoose apply to all empty cells it works as expected. but as soon as I use any formula styles are all over the place.

Any ideas?

Here is an example of the spreadsheet I am working with https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Y-2jeKue9aH4gGdKHZjECygo47JFOp2W11C2sy7fJk/edit#gid=553917738

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the conditional formatting via formula that can be a little tricky. The solution you need is:

```
=K$12="Not Paid"
```

This is because when you use =K12="Not Paid" it uses relative references. That means that if you apply this conditional formula in a range like "A12:A2", for cell "A12" the formula will be exactly as you wrote, but for cell "A13" it will have a formula like =K13="Not Paid", which is not true. I hope you can take a look on this more in depth [tutorial](https://yagisanatode.com/2019/03/02/google-sheets-conditional-formatting-with-custom-formula/).

Comment: Thanks @Jonas Negri. I think that what I was missing. additional thanks for tutorial link, it's broken, but I found info about relative vs absolute references on another resource..

Comment: I wonder is it actually possible to add more dynamic conditional formatting, so that I wouldn't have to recreate colours one by one for each status?

Comment: Like, is it possible to do something such as: If K12 has a colour,  A11:A26 cell background should match it as well

Comment: As far was I'm aware there's nothing like this for native Google Sheets.
With Google Scripts it would be a simple thing to do, but that would require a "onEdit" script.

Comment: I guess I am complicating things as always haha.

Answer (score 2):

all you need is to extend the range to **K12:K** like:

[image: 0]

---

## UPDATE:

**let R10 be:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({K12; IF(IF(LEN(B11:B&D11:D&K11:K), VLOOKUP(ROW(A11:A), IF({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}<>"", {row(A11:A), {IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}}), 2, 1), )<>"",   IF(LEN(B11:B&D11:D&K11:K), VLOOKUP(ROW(A11:A), IF({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}<>"", {ROW(A11:A), {IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}}), 2, 1), ), QUERY(IF(LEN(B11:B&D11:D&K11:K), VLOOKUP(ROW(A11:A), IF({IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}<>"", {ROW(A11:A), {IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(K12:K,
 "Undefined|Quote|Accepted|In-progress|Cancelled|On-hold|Not Paid|Paid 50%|Closed"));""}}), 2, 1), ), "offset 1", 0))})
```

[image: 0]

---

**and S9 be:**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"";IF(INDIRECT("R9:R"&ROWS(A9:A)-1)="", 1, )})
```

[image: 0]

---

**then red color will be:**

```
=($R11="Not Paid")*($S11<>1)
```

[image: 0]

---

**and green color will be:**

```
=($R11="Closed")*($S11<>1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thanks for chipping in. However, I think I did not explain myself properly. I know how to make conditional formatting for status cells. I needed to add a new conditional formatting to the column of cells(A11 to A26) based on the status colour

Comment: its possible if you would not mind a helper column (?)

Comment: well, as long as it doesn't complicated, make messy or heavy my sheet, I don't mind. Nevertheless I am curious to see

Comment: but I can't figure out how it works.. like what does len do? why do you need B & D columns?

Comment: LEN checks for characters count so combined with `=IF(LEN(A1), true, false)` means "if A1 contains more than 0 characters do true otherwise do false". and B & D columns are "needed" just because rows in them (combined) are mostly populated